# How to order by date when a column is of type nvarchar in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue where I created a column `sent_Date` of type `nvarchar` while it's storing date and time.

Now when I try to sort it by date, it's not doing so correctly.

I am using this query:

```
select *
from tbl_skip 
where sent_date > '9/27/2020 7:29:11 PM'
order by SENT_DATE desc
```

Comment: Fix your data, so you use the correct type to store the date/time.  That is the simplest solution.

Comment: Why *are* you storing Date and Time data in a `nvarchar` in the first place? There are multiple [Date and time types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-and-time-types?view=sql-server-ver15) that are far more appropriate.

Comment: Besides ordering, what do you think is the result of `'11/27/2020 7:29:11 PM' > '9/27/2020 7:29:11 PM'`?

Comment: I have used the below and it worked fine for me select  *
from tbl_skip 
where CONVERT(datetime,SENT_DATE) > '2020-09-28 19:29:11.000'
order by
CONVERT(datetime,SENT_DATE) desc

Answer (score 2):

Like the comments have said, the *real* solution here is fix your design. That means changing the column's data type an `nvarchar` to a date and time data type, I'm going to use a `datetime2(0)` here, as your data is accurate to a second, so seems the most appropriate.

Firstly we need to convert the value to as ISO value. I'm also, however, going to create a new column called `Bad_Sent_Date`, to store values that could not be converted. Experience has taught many of us that systems that incorrectly use string data types to store dates (or numerical data) rarely have good data integrity rules on the value (because if they did, it wouldn't be an `nvarchar`) to start, so have bad values like '`29/02/2019'` or mix styles, such as having both `'09/29/2020'` *and* `'29/09/2020'`.

Based on the single example we have, I will *assume* your data is supposed to be in the format `MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_skip ADD Bad_Sent_Date nvarchar(30) NULL;
GO
UPDATE TABLE dbo.tbl_skip 
SET Bad_Sent_Date = CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),Sent_date,101) IS NULL THEN Sent_date END,
    Sent_Date = CONVERT(nvarchar(30),TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),Sent_date,101),126);
GO
```

Now we have an ISO format, we can change the table's data type:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_skip ALTER COLUMN Sent_date datetime2(0) NULL;
```

Note that if you *do* have constraints on the column `Sent_date`, or it isn't `NULL`able, you will first need to `DROP` said `CONSTRAINT`s, change the column to be `NULL`able and then recreate said `CONSTRAINT`s after you have altered the column.

You can also review the "dates" that failed to be converted with the following:

```sql
SELECT bad_sent_date
FROM dbo.tbl_skip
WHERE bad_sent_date IS NOT NULL
  AND Sent_date IS NULL;
```

Once that's all done, then your query simply needs an update to use an unambiguous date literal, and it'll work:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbl_skip
WHERE sent_date > '2020-09-27T19:29:11' --'9/27/2020 7:29:11 PM'
ORDER BY SENT_DATE DESC;
```

Comment: I have used the below and it worked fine select  *
from tbl_skip 
where CONVERT(datetime,SENT_DATE) > '2020-09-28 19:29:11.000'
order by
CONVERT(datetime,SENT_DATE) desc

Comment: But that doesn't fix the pronlem, @ahmed .

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the data from string to datetime.
Please note i used 100 as an example to convert to date time. You can use below link to see if its behaving correctly. link -https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

```
select *
from tbl_skip 
where sent_date > convert(datetime,'9/27/2020 7:29:11 PM',100)
ORDER BY  CONVERT(datetime,SENT_DATE,100) desc
```

Comment: Thank you, i have used the below select  *
from tbl_skip 
where CONVERT(datetime,SENT_DATE) > '2020-09-28 19:29:11.000'
order by
CONVERT(datetime,SENT_DATE) desc

Comment: Its always good to give a format but hey, if it works then i am happy :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convert it to a datetime

```
select *
from tbl_skip 
where sent_date > '9/27/2020 7:29:11 PM'
order by convert(datetime,SENT_DATE) desc
```

Just make sure the data in column is legit. If so, it would make sense to convert the column type to a datetime.

```
alter table tbl_skip alter column SENT_DATE datetime
```

If the data is mixed, you may need to fix it or use something like

```
order by try_convert(datetime,SENT_DATE) desc
```

Comment: Beware of all these convert by Jeremy or Koushik, because they won't work in production ONLY if the session of the connected user is ENGLISH. For all other user of anykind the string formated date does not use the same pattern. So the advices of  Gordon and Larnu are the most correct answers...

Comment: I have used this select  *
from tbl_skip 
where CONVERT(datetime,SENT_DATE) > '2020-09-28 19:29:11.000'
order by
CONVERT(datetime,SENT_DATE) desc